# insert trigger on ms sql

Tags: sql-server, триггер

Есть таблицы: заказчик, заказ, книга, книги в заявках

```
CREATE TABLE client --Заказчик
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50) NULL
);

CREATE TABLE request --Заказ
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    id_client INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES client(id),
    create_date DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
);

CREATE TABLE book_in_request  --Издание в заказах
(
    id_book INTEGER  FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES book(id),
    id_request INTEGER  FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES request(id),
    qty INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (qty > 0),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_book, id_request)
);

CREATE TABLE book --Книга
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    public_year DATE NOT NULL,
    pgs INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK(pgs > 0)
);
```

Нужно написать триггер который запретит заказчику заказывать больше 5 заказов в неделю в целом или больше 100 книг в неделю, помогите разобраться, в sql я не очень силен, и триггеры на запрет вставки не писал ни разу) спасибо заранее..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше бы все-таки все проверки делать до вставки в базу. Но если уж обязательно делать имеено триггером, то думаю вот этот вариант Вам подойдет

```
CREATE TRIGGER [имя триггера] AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS([здесь нужно вставить запрос, проверяющий, что заказчик достиг своего лимита])
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RAISERROR ('[сообщение об ошибке]', 16, 1)
    END
END
```

Два ключевых момента.

1. триггер `AFTER INSERT`. Т.е. запись создастся все равно.
2. `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` - это то, что сотрет запись, если она не нужна

Comment: если триггер не принимает передаваемые параметры, то как проверить это к заказчику то есть определенный заказчик не может больше 5 в неделю и 100 книг..?

Comment: Как это "триггер не принимает параметры"? Есть же New и Old recordset...

Comment: хм хм..запутали, триггер пишется под определенное действие - вставка/удаление/изменение...и срабатывает при нем допустим - insert into table values (val1, val2 val3) ..вот как перехватить эти самые val1/2/3 ?

Comment: да, под определенное действие С ОПРЕДЕЛЕННОЙ ЗАПИСЬЮ. Вам нужно почитать про ms-sql триггеры. Но в общих чертах так: когда триггер обрабатывает запись, она зранится в системных скрытых таблицах. `inserted` - это новая запись. `deleted` - это старая запись. Т.е. для триггера на вставку `deleted` не существует. Для триггера на `update` - существуют оба. Для триггера на `delete` не существует `inserted`.

Comment: читаю читаю...особо ничего про них..

Comment: И обращаться к ним надо как к рекордсету. Например: `UPDATE [table] SET [fld]=X FROM inserted i JOIN deleted d ON i.id=d.id AND i.status<>d.status`. Этот триггер поставить Х в [fld] если в новой записи `status` отличается от старой. В Вашем случае надо рекордсет `inserted` использовать для вычислений, подразумевая, что `inserted.client_id` это `id` клиента